JDBC connection using serverless compute on databricks
I want to use serverless compute on databricks to establish connection to mysql rds cluster and obtain the data.
I tried to use the below query, it runs on other clusters except serverlesscompute.
I found that serverless compute currently does not support jdbc due to inability to add jar files.
My question is, Is there any other method for me to establish connection to get data from mysql rds cluster?

I tried the mentioned code using python and sql. But it does not work for servelss code.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code as properly formatted text.
